# Software to clean windows junk file

Tags: windows-10, temporary-files, disk-cleanup, software-update

I'm looking for any free software or way around to clean junk files and make more space available in Windows drive.

Using Windows 10

Comment: By junk files do you mean malware?  Or are you just trying to free up drive space?

Comment: This question is off-topic as it asks for product recommendations, however I can suggest using [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many (hundreds) such free software. CCleaner is very good. If you're looking to clean up space, clean out the following two locations as well. None of the cleaning software clean these locations.
1) C:\Windows\Installer\$PatchCache$\Managed
2) C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download
Delete their contents only.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can use the built-tin Disk Cleanup tool to remove the temporary internet files, thumbnails,browser caches and others. If you do like software, you can use FileCleaner.

Comment: Between Windows 7 and 10, the stock Disk Cleanup tool is there ready to do a quite adequate job at cleaning temps, memory dumps, old Windows Update files under SoftwareDistribution and actually optimizes the WinSXS folder afterwards, something that CCleaner probably doesn't take into account.